# How to include random salt with password variable in php

Tags: php, passwords, password-protection, salt

I have a pssword variable where it contains the user's password which contains some stirngs at the start and end of the password so that it salts the password. Below is the code for this:

```
$teacherpassword = md5(md5("j92".$teacherpassword."djS"));
```

Obviously the characters chosen to salt the password would be the same character for all the passwords.

What I want is to create a random characters generator so that the first 3 characters and the last 3 characters of the salt are all random so each password will have a random salt.

Below is the php generator create to pick out characters at random for the salt:

```
$salt = ""; 
for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) { 
   $salt .= substr(
     "./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789", 
     mt_rand(0, 63), 
     1); 
}
```

My question is that how do I get the generator to pick out 6 random characters for the salt, and then stick 3 of those characters in front of the passowrd and th other 3 at the end of the password?

FOR EXAMPLE:

PASSWORD 1 could be:  $teacherpassword = md5(md5("jfs".$teacherpassword."sfS"));
PASSWORD 2 could be:  $teacherpassword = md5(md5("4f3".$teacherpassword.p.S"));
PASSWORD 3 could be:  $teacherpassword = md5(md5("wpw".$teacherpassword."qq2"));

As you can see all passwords contain their own salt thanks to the php random generator for the salt

Comment: You can add the salt to the beginning, or to the end, since it is easier to do and not less secured

Comment: @Gabriel Santos: actually adding rounds isn't that "funny". But it makes sense to add several thousands, not just a couple

Comment: @zerkms I think `hash('ANY SHA-2 HERE', 'SALT WITH PASSWORD HERE')` is more logic..

Comment: @Gabriel Santos: it is even better to have sha-512, but `md5(md5())` isn't really lol ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really simple solution would be to use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

> **substr** — Return part of a string

```
$randomSalt = "abcdef";

$preSalt = substr($randomSalt, 0,3); // abc
$postSalt = substr($randomSalt, 3,3);  // def

$password = md5(md5($preSalt.$teacherpassword.$postSalt));
```

---

One more suggestion for you would be to use PHP's [`uniqueid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function to generate random salt for your passwords.

> **uniqid** — Generate a unique ID

Comment: Just one little question, if I do `$preSalt = substr($randomSalt,  mt_rand(0, 63),3);`, will that pick any 3 characters from the list of characters?

Comment: Yes, the third parameter for `substr` is the length of the sting you want to get back.

Comment: @user1626268: why do you put salt on either side of the password? Why not just append to the end?

Comment: @zer - Hackers wouldn't be expecting it on **both** sides ;)  It's just another level of obfuscation I guess...

Comment: @Lix: uhm, security through obscurity?

Comment: @zerkms I saw a youtube video on password salting and the person put it on either side of the password, so I thought I will do same thing

Comment: @user1626268: it doesn't bring anything to overall security. It's the same as having salt added to only the beginning or only to the end;